# Read, update or create assets only through the Transaction Processor Functions

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want people who connect to the business network only to have access through the code that I wrote in the Transaction Processor Functions, without having the possibility to read, update or create the assets outside of my code, this is because I want a logic to process transactions. That's possible?
For example, I give a creation permission to a person, but I want that person to be able to create only under certain conditions.
I know it's possible to have a logic in the access control language, but that's not enough for what I'm doing.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this post answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643232/hyperledger-composer-access-control-allow-create-in-transaction/50644017

Comment: Thank you so much!! that's just what I needed!! :)